# jQuery: Can't select all inputs and on keydown select 'this' and show next element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm attempting to use jquery to select all inputs in the HTML document below and on the 'keydown' event select 'this' and then show the next element.

My jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hint').hide();
});
    $('input').keydown(function(){
        $(this).show();
});
```

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of my Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>
    <input type="text"><span class="hint">Something cool</span>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isnt clear what you are asking but your second function isnt being run after the page is ready so be careful about loading the DOM before the script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.hint').hide();

    $('input').keydown(function(){
        $(this).show();
    });

});
```

To get the next element to show change the line to this:

```
 $(this).next().show();
```

Comment: This shouldn't matter as long as the script is loaded after the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using the .next( [selector] ) function in jQuery. ( I assumed that you want to show the .hint span )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hint').hide();
});
$('input').keydown(function() {
    $(this).next('.hint').show();
});​
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/RQ3zw/

Comment: Thanks! Yeah wasn't aware that I could use .next like that.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Found it!

Just needed to add

```
 $(this).next().show();
```

in place of

```
$(this).show();
```

So completed this would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hint').hide();
});
    $('input').keydown(function(){
        $(this).next().show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.next()` selector:

`$(this).next('.hint').show();`

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/senoramor/jjPkJ/)